# Running multiple selenium testNG classes without testNG.xml file in a maven project

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have just been researching on why I should start using maven for my selenium scripts in eclipse and things so far look good; however, It is unclear why I would need a testng.xml file to run multiple testNG classes when normally you can just right click on the project name in package explorer and choose the run as testNG test option which would run all classes in the project. I believe run as a maven test will do the same.  Why then is the xml file necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It provides additional mechanizm to configure and run you tests. 
Modern build tools (maven, gradle) provide solutions which override most part of functionality of testng.xml.

But TestNG xml/yaml is still very usefull. TestNG's internals manage tests as XmlSuite, XmlTest, XmlClass. So it is very easy to convert your xml to test objects or back and use it for dynamic test suite generation. And xml gives you a clear view on what and how you tests will be executed.

Which tool to use depends on size and needs of your project. In some big projects we generate xml dynamically during compilation. In others pre-build it with gradle.

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386805/webdriver-can-login-in-chrome-not-in-firefox-unable-to-find-owning-document?noredirect=1#comment68047438_40386805